# Netbeans slow when connected to WLAN

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, archlinux

Whenever I start netbeans while I'm connected to a wireless network it starts really slow (it takes about 1 to 2 minutes).
When I'm not connected to the internet (or connected through another device like a usb modem or LAN) it starts within 5 to 10 seconds.

The same thing seems to happen with all java applications that have a gui.
Once the programs have started they run fast and I don't experience any difference no matter if I'm connected to a wireless network or not.

So far I have tried a few things including switching between OracleJDK and OpenJDK, reinstalling netbeans and setting the max ram to 8GB for the processes. Unfortunately none of these actions have shown any positive effect.

At the moment I happen to be developing a sophisticated gui in java and it drives me crazy that I have to wait 15 to 30 seconds until it starts.

Can anyone help me with this one?

Here is some information I think is needed/useful:
My OS: Arch linux
Network management tool: NetworkManager

If you need any further information just ask.

Answer (score 0):

This might be long shot, but if you are sure it's because of the internet you can try to block the internet connection of the netbeans.

[How to block internet access to certain programs on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/550276/how-to-block-internet-access-to-certain-programs-on-linux)

I hope that helped!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the internet connection is not the problem just the wireless network connection. When I'm connected to the internet via a usb modem or LAN all java applications start up fast.